# JavaScript: Setting Nested object value by ID

Tags: javascript, object, collections, nested, set

I would like to know what is the best way to update the member of the multilevel object collection in JavaScript

Here is the simplified version of my collection:

```
this.Steps = [

{ id: 1, text: "test", childSteps: 
  [
    { id: 2, text: "test"},
    { id: 3, text: "test"},
    { id: 4, text: "test", childSteps: 
    [
           { id: 10, text: "test"},
           { id: 11, text: "test"}
    ]}
    },
    { id: 5, text: "test"},
    { id: 6, text: "test"},
    { id: 7, text: "test"},    
    { id: 8, text: "test"},
    { id: 9, text: "test"}
  ]
}
];
```

The ideal would be to have a function to be called like:

```
updateObjectByID(11, 'string to be set');
```

This is easy to be done when we have only 1 level of objects. But when using recursion on multilevel collection its getting much harder.

I'm currently using a function that is parsing the whole collection and building string like :

```
this.Steps[0].childSteps[3].childSteps[1].text == "string to be set"
```

and then I do `eval()` on that string.

I'm sure there might be a much cleaner solution.

Using eval is making my class impossible to compress btw.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "*Parsing the whole collection*"… and then you still had to use `eval` after this? Can't believe that, please show us that code.

Comment: Infact am parsing the whole collection and building string in order to update the collection member.

Comment: If i change the object parameter it will only change on the reference of the object and not on my collection, since when doing recursion am sending the childSteps as reference.

Comment: I cannot paste it as answer, so i will edit the question

Answer (score 2):

You can build a map of objects by id for direct access:

```
var map = {};
(function recurse(steps) {
    for (var i=0; i<steps.length; i++) {
        var step = steps[i];
        map[ step.id ] = step;
        if ("childSteps" in step)
            recurse(step.childSteps);
    }
})(this.Steps);

function updateObjectByID(id, string) {
    map[id].text = string;
}
```

---

A comment on your code: You overcomplified a lot. When the condition `if(obj.id == objId)` is met, you have your `obj` reference already!!! Now there is absolutely no need to search for a path to it, build a string from that, and eval it. Just assign directly to its property!

```
function(steps, objId, value, whatParam, command) {
    if (typeof whatParam == 'undefined')
        whatParam = 'selected';
    $.each(steps, function(index, obj){
        if(obj.id == objId) {
            // removed a lot of unecessary stuff

            // not sure, looks like "value" was evaled sometimes as well
            obj[whatParam] = value;

         } // insert an "else" here if ids are unique
         if (typeof obj.childSteps != 'undefined') {           
             this.setupObjectState(obj.childSteps, objId, value, whatParam, command);
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: woow this one works :). But i really dont understand how!?! Anyway thank you very much for your help!

Comment: They are just references to the exact same object in your `Steps` array.

Comment: about the simplified version... that function was doing many other things then just updating one object. It was managing conflicting steps (if you select one it deselect another ones etc...) sometime the command needed to be evaled before the object was actually found. I know this solution is very ugly and inefficient but now with the above one it will be as clean as hospital.

Comment: I see that MAP object is containing all steps at the same level, but i dont understand how comes its changing this.Steps members when updating map[something]

Comment: Object values are just pointers to some memory. And so, `this.Steps[0].childSteps[1]` and `map[3]` point to exactly the same thing. And if you change a property on that thing, you can see it regardless from which reference you look at the thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you call `updateObjectById()` with an ID, the ID has to be unique. Why don´t you change your structure like this then:

```
this.Steps = [
    { id: 1, text: "test" },
    { id: 2, parent: 1, text: "test" },
    { id: 3, parent: 1, text: "test" },
    { id: 4, parent: 1, text: "test" },
    { id: 10, parent: 4, text: "test" },
    { id: 11, parent: 4, text: "test" },
    { id: 5, parent: 1, text: "test"},
    { id: 6, parent: 1, text: "test"},
    { id: 7, parent: 1, text: "test"},    
    { id: 8, parent: 1, text: "test"},
    { id: 9, parent: 1, text: "test"}
]
```

This way you can easily update your entries like this:

```
function updateObjectByID(id, text) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.Steps.length; i++) {
        if(this.Steps[i].id === id) {
            this.Steps[i].text = text;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

With the extra attribute `parent` you can still easily get all the children of an element like this:

```
function getChildrenByID(id) {
    var array = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < this.Steps.length; i++) {
        if(this.Steps[i].parent === id) {
            array.push(this.Steps[i]);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's an inefficient data structure!

Comment: Yes, instead of accessing anything directly by a property you always have to filter the whole array.

Comment: This is an intresting solution too, but the problem is that my collection is sent from the backend, and everything else is using it like it is now so this would be a big job.

Answer (score 0):

You must recursively descend your tree structure searching for the object with the target "id" and replace its text.  For example:

```
function updateObjectByID(obj, id, text) {
  if (!obj) return;
  if (obj.id === id) {
    obj.text = text;
  } else if ((typeof(obj)==='object') && (obj.constructor===Array)) {
    for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
      updateObjectByID(obj[i], id, text);
    }
  } else if (obj.childSteps) {
    updateObjectByID(obj.childSteps, id, text);
  }
}

updateObjectByID(this.Steps, 11, 'String to be set');
```

However, this solution can be optimized by tree pruning.

Comment: Notice that `this.Steps` is an array, not the "root step".

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateObjectByID(id, text) {
    (function setText(steps) {
        for(var i = 0; i < steps.length; i++){
            var step = steps[i];
            if(step.id === id){
                step.text = text;
            }
            if ("childSteps" in step){
                setText(step.childSteps);
            }
        }
    })(this.Steps);
}
```

Here is demo. http://jsfiddle.net/qDWX8/

Comment: This one looks almost the same as Bergis one. Except that i dont see a map object. And this one works too. Seeing this, i dont understand why my first versions of that function were not working. They were pretty much the same as this, but the result was that the object in the functions scope was updated (obj), but not in my main collection (this.Steps).